# Remove maximise button on iBooks HTML widget

Tags: ibooks

I've added a PNG animation (acting like a animated GIF) to an iBook HTML widget using CSS, JavaScript and HTML.

The problem is that there is a maximize button when hovering over the widget in the iBook preview. I want to remove this because it is only supposed to be an animation that plays when entering the page, and I don't want the user to be able to interact with it.

[image]

How can I remove this functionality from the widget?

Comment: just remove the click event on it using javascript or jquery

Comment: could you explain one way of doing this? I tried returning false on the image's 'onclick' event, however this didn't work

Comment: `$('image').off('click')` or `$('image').unbind('click')`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the widget width and height in your `info.plist` file the same as the width and height in iBooks author prevents opening in full screen when tapping on it.

I don't know if this logic works on Mac or iPhone, but it seems to work on the iPad.